# Why while loop never ends(I am asking it again)

Tags: c

EDIT: Yes, i forgot the pointer thank you but still why isn't ending? while i only check for str, it ends but when i check for str and str != 32 it never ends, even though me forgetting pointer makes str != 32 always 1, str becomes 0 at some point(i check it when using it alone), why it doesn't become 0 at some point when i include str != 32 ?

Code is for question from leetcode: String to Integer (atoi)

```
int myAtoi(char *str)
{
   while(str && str != 32)
       ++str;
}
```

I omit the other parts of it, this while loop never ending in my program (it is the first statement nothing to do with the other part of the code)

I also tried str != ' ' && str and str != 32 && str != '\0', but whenever I check for whitespace, the loop never ends, why it doesn't end? I am just checking a statement, for example this is fine:

```
int myAtoi(char *str)
{
   while(str)
       ++str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str` is a pointer. It's value is never null, or convertable to false.  `*str` is a char and will be null when a char of `\0` is found.